# How to connect to client after installing db2 in docker?

Tags: database, docker, db2

I am tried installing DB2 in Mac using Docker. I installed it. But how to connect to the server from any client example(DbVisualizer) Today only i heard about this application so i am novice on it.

I tried to give 
database server - localhost
port:50000
Database:SAMPLE(which is present)

even ping is not working for above db details. Am i missing anything?

Comment: You bind port to host machine when run container?
`docker run -p 5000:5000 image_name`

Comment: my bad docker is configured to use the default machine ip. instead of that ip i used localhost. after using configured IP i am able to connect to db